# Custom Spring Actuator Endpoint which has subsystem and can be added dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm looking for a way to implement custom endpoints for a reactive application using Spring Boot 2.2.

The endpoints have some subsystems and perform specific resource operations on the subsystems. The URL paths look like:

```
/actuator/system1/subsystem_a
/actuator/system1/subsystem_b
/actuator/system2/subsystem_c
```

Furthermore, system1 and system2 are not both always deployed, so I'd like to add dynamically the endpoints of the deployed system only.

I know I can use `ReactiveHealthContributorRegistry` to add custom health check endpoints dynamically. Is there a similar way for a fully custom endpoint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way to construct such complex endpoints like what I asked in Spring Boot Actuator.

I finally decided to use `RouterFunction` and `HandlerFunction` referring to the following websites.

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-functional-web
- https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/22/new-in-spring-5-functional-web-framework